# Is there a way to handle exceptions but only from a specific library?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I am using a package (foo) and am calling a method in a class (Foo) within that package.  Let's say that package has its own exceptions defined:

```
exception foo.exceptions.FooEx_1
exception foo.exceptions.FooEx_2
...
exception foo.exceptions.FooEx_n
```

I'd prefer not to write a generic exception handler:

```
try:
except:
  # Process any exception here
```

I just want to catch only exceptions raised in the foo library/package.  Is there a way to do that?  Like:

```
try:
except foo.exceptions.*
```

Comment: The library should (hopefully) do you the courtesy of implementing a base exception from which the others derive?

Comment: So then it would just be:  except BaseExceptionClass: ?

Answer (score 1):

If all of the exceptions in `foo.exceptions` subclass some base `foo.exceptions.BaseFooException` class, you can catch it:

```
>>> assert issubclass(NotImplementedError, RuntimeError)
>>>
>>> try:
...     raise NotImplementedError()
... except RuntimeError:
...     print('Caught it')
...
Caught it
```

Otherwise, you will have to extract all of the exceptions from the module:

```
all_exceptions = tuple(getattr(foo.exceptions, e) for e in dir(foo.exceptions) if e.startswith('FooEx'))
```

And filter on them:

```
try:
    ...
except all_exceptions as e:
    # We caught it
```

Comment: It's probably simpler to make `all_exceptions` a tuple and do `except all_exceptions as e`.